# Updating Multiple Google Calendars With New Schedule

Tags: google-calendar

Currently I have 3 Google calendars that I use to keep track of things.

I would like to share the information in all three with someone so that they can see my availability (and keep track of that availability as I make updates to the calendars) however I currently have to give them access to all three calendars.

Moreover, so they have an accurate representation of my availability, they have to make sure that they are viewing all three of my calendars when they look at my schedule.

Is there currently a way in Google to "merge" all three calendars and then make sure that they stay updated whenever I make a new event in any of the three? The benefit here is that the person I send the calendars to only has to keep track of one calendar with all of my availability.

As a fix I can import one calendar to another, but using the ICS file method it appears that the calendars don't update events I make later on when I do this.

I am open to creating a 4th calendar to share just with them but again the updating issue comes into play if I simply import all of my events.